# Read attributes of movie files in Flash / Flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex

If I have a movie file, how can I get its attributes such as length, bit rate, and so on, if at all possible?
Thanks.

Comment: That may depend on how they were encoded. (What codec was used?) Do you know that or could it be anything?

Comment: I need it for the FLV,MOV,MP4 encodings.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the information you need using the FLVPlayback component, either drag one on to the stage if using the Flash IDE or add to the library and attach dynamically.

All the properties you need like bitrate, duration (accessed through metadata object) are available to you, check out the docs on the [FLVPlayback Class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html)